# ksh autocomplete and previous commands together

Tags: shell, ksh

`set -o vi-tabcomplete` is turning on tab autocomplete

and

`set -o emacs` is turning on history ( up for previous command, down for next command )

But, if I set both in ~/.kshrc, it is turning on only one which is emacs(history) and I am not able to turn on tab autocomplete. Am I missing something?

```
set -o vi-tabcomplete
set -o emacs
```

---

Did the following

```
set -o emacs

Esc, Ctrl V -- This gave me 
$ Version AJM 93t+ 2010-02-02
```

Also tried doing

```
$ set -o emacs
$ bind "^I=complete"
ksh: bind: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Also put these things in .kshrc

```
set -o emacs
bind "^I=complete"
```

Now, the history alone is working, not tab complete.

Answer (score 3):

The options vi and emacs are mutually exclusive.

Check your ksh version and update your question, please:

```
set -o emacs 
Ctrl-V          # (yes, press control-v) this prints ksh version
```

Try:

```
set -o emacs
bind "^I=complete"      # tab completion
```

What I don't remember is whether you enter literally caret-I or  control-I to get the correct bind.

Comment: I tried doing "bind ^I=complete" but doesn't work. Failed with error saying bind: not found. I'm using ksh88. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Too bad, ksh88 doesn't have this functionality. For this reason I try to avoid it at all costs. If I need to use it, I would set -o vi and use Esc-\ and Esc-= key sequences (that is, escape-backslash and escape-equal).

Answer (score 2):

In my version **Version M-11/16/88f** using a **ksh** shell not the ksh93 i get it running using two times the ESC key. Also instead of a normal way of using tab then two times the ESC key. But the behaviour is not the same is more simple that in a normal shell sh or bash when you presh TAB key you get a list of possible matches with the string you already have. Using this shell and pressing the ESC key 2 times you will get only an autocomplete when there is only one case that match. If you want to see how many cases you can use "ESC + =" combination and then continue writing.

Resume:

"ESC + ESC" => autocomplete when there is only a match case.

"ESC + =" => show all the match cases.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

Type in ~/.environ.ksh the following

```
set -o tabcomplete  # Auto Tab complete
set -o emacs        # History
```

Answer (score 0):

check your shell using echo $0 --> if this is ksh then.
make an entry in .profile as : set -o vi

1. for all last command executed use the keyword as : ESC+k(for backward last executed command) and ESC+j (for forward command)
2. for auto pathcompletation use the command as ESC+\

Answer (score -1):

Just add these 2 lines in your `.profile` file at the end to fix this issue:

```
SHELL=/bin/ksh # Correct it if your ksh is at different path
exec $SHELL    # To fix autocomplete bug of standard ksh. It must be last line.
```